# mod_rewrite to remove SSO(single sign on) - junction name in URL

Tags: mod-rewrite, apache2, single-sign-on

I have  a SSO url -

```
http://<server>/<junction>/<application_context>/ssoLogin.do
e.g. http://pingu.intranet.com/tms/mint/ssoLogin.do
```

Once user hits this url. SSO junction appends headers and redirects to Apache webserver. My goal is to remove the SSO junction name once the request reaches Apache(where I am using ProxyPass and AJP to connect to Tomcat App).

Issue is mod_rewrite is picking the URI - /mint/ssoLogin.do. so I can not remove the junction name /tms. e.g. rewrite.log says

```
init rewrite engine with requested uri /mint/js/jquery/jquery.min.js
```

My conf file looks like

```
    ProxyPreserveHost On

# define the balancer, with http and/ or ajp connections
<Proxy balancer://application_cl>
    BalancerMember ajp://pingu01.intranet.com:8009 route=node1 disablereuse=on retry=0
    BalancerMember ajp://pingu02.intranet.com:8009 route=node2 disablereuse=on retry=0
</Proxy>


# Vendor Product ProxyPass Settings
ProxyPass /mint balancer://application_cl/mint stickysession=JSESSIONID|jsessionid nofailover=On
ProxyPassReverse /mint balancer://application_cl/mint

# Custom settings to remove junction name for proper javascript loading

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/tms/
RewriteRule ^/tms/(.*)  /$1
</IfModule>


# RequestHeader settings(as per Product documentation)
SetEnvIf X-Forwarded-Proto .+ HAVE_X_FORWARDED_PROTO
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "http" env=!HAVE_X_FORWARDED_PROTO
```

Comment: OK. Issue is resolved. I printed out all the server variables as HTTP Headers and found that the SSO junction doesn't pass the junction name to web servers.                                                          Solution: we created a transparent junction with the name /mint.